# Is there a Webbrowser control that supports html5 video (WebRTC) available for .Net?

Tags: c#, winforms, html, webkit, webrtc

I was looking for a way to embed a page that hosts WebRTC video such as the demo from http://www.webrtc.org/demo into a WinForms app so the user doesn't need to install nor launch any external browsers that may contain toolbars, etc, I looked into a few components such as GeckoFX and WebKit.Net but they fail to load the webcam video.
Do you know of any hack or other project that may support WebRTC inside .Net?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium Embedded Framework claims to support WebRTC (I haven't confirmed it myself).

https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

Comment: Thanks, I checked that and it seems that Xilium CefGlue is the only library at the moment that added webrtc support however there are no binaries to download, I got the source and built the solution on Visual studio without errors but none of the demos work due to a dll being missing, I can't seem to find that dll, can I get some help?

Comment: the error: Unable to load DLL 'libcef': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: Note that cef and the glue(s) are different components. cef is the browser part. The glue is a separate component that makes it possible to use cef from your specific environment (such as from .net). It seems like you only have the glue, not cef. Other than that I can't help you, because I haven't done this myself.

Comment: CEF works with command line argument "--enable-media-stream", I would just need now to get Glue working with CEF.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC  is supported by Mozilla Firefox:

http://www.webrtc.org/

If you want to embed Firefox in you project you can easily embed [GeckoFX](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx) web browser control in your Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 0):

The GeckoFX engine (Mozilla Firefox) says it can use WebRTC. This seem to be right (as far as I have seen yet) but there seem to be a problem with some parts of it. I'm using it actual for WebRTC and have a problem with the video part - see here: [Embedded GeckoFx in C#.NET - WebRTC Video not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204508/embedded-geckofx-in-c-net-webrtc-video-not-working)

Comment: CEFSharp is the way to go. If you're using visual studio just install using Package Manager.

Comment: I tried CEFSharp from the actual nuget Sources (the 51.0) - WebRTC is not working with CEFSharp, too, like GeckoFx. The little thing it does better, it simply shows nothing and do not crash like GeckoFx.

Comment: Did you use the "--enable-media-stream" command line parameter?

//settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1"); //Enable WebRTC