# Alternative to WebBrowser Control for .Net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I have to use a WebBrowser Control to display a webpage and show the HTML code of the page to the user.
I used the WebBrowser Control from .net, but i found out, after days of searching, that it has a very very critical memory leak:
[How to get around the memory leak in the .NET Webbrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302933/how-to-get-around-the-memory-leak-in-the-net-webbrowser-control)

I had a look for hours to fix it, but I didn't see a chance to do that.

So I need another way - What is the alternative of this control?

Comment: You can find some options at http://stackoverflow.com/q/16797435/1105687 But that question is five months old now so perhaps there are better options now.

Comment: This doesn't look like controls O.o

Comment: They are. From the CEF page: _...a Web browser control based on the Google Chromium project..._ From the GeckoFx page: _..GeckoFX is a cross platform Webrowser control for embedding into WinForms Applications..._

Comment: I used GeckoFX, thank you very much!

Comment: You may want to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy the [GeckoFX Browser](https://code.google.com/p/geckofx/)!